# Custom loss function fails with standard loss inside

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am having a trouble with custom loss function in Keras. The tasks seems fairly simple, but cannot progress due to unexpected behavior. The idea is to join `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` with some extras. First I wanted to confirm that if I just user sparse categorical crossentropy in the custom loss function, it will not change networks training.

the default solution is to set

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",...)
```

this works no problem. network learns and shows improvement in both training and validation accuracy.

however, when I define custom loss

```
def new_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    ls = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
    return ls(y_true,y_pred)
```

the network fails to train.

training and validation accuracy decrease to 0.09... with no hope of proper training.

moreover, if I do the following

```
model.compile(loss= tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),...)
```

network is trained well.

Tensorflow version is

```
tf.__version__ = '1.15.3'
```

Keras version is

```
keras.__version__ = '2.2.4-tf'
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" with your loss function and it worked fine for my example, did you manage to get it working?

```
model.compile(loss=new_loss,...)
```